# Given secret, learn account details

Tags: ripple, ripple-api

I'm building a tool that uses ripple-lib on the client side and ripple-rest on the server side.  For some features, I need the administrator to provide the account secret.

I could prompt the user for both the account ID and the secret.  Instead, I want to prompt for only the secret and calculate the account ID automatically.  That way, I'll always have a valid matching ID and secret.

I'm certain this can be done, as the client at https://ripple.com/client/#/register allows you to enter the secret and it does exactly what I'm talking about.

I can't find any documentation as to how it does this.  Does ripple-lib provide an API for calculating the account ID, given the secret?

Comment: See [my answer to a different question](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/18880/3364). It describes and links to the process of turning a secret into a key and a Ripple address. Make sure that Ripple secrets are not being sent over non-secure links or to third party servers (e.g. you shouldn't distribute your ripple-lib based tool and expect people to point it to a ripple-rest server you run).

Comment: Thanks for links (although currently, they're all greek to me).  I get that about the secrets.  My finished product may generate new accounts to avoid the passing of any secrets.  For my prototype, I'm simply prompting for both public id and secret.